# Refining Python code for use (skipping repeated steps)

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have been working on a project which requires splitting 10-12 columns and stacking them. The only problem is I have to do it repeatedly. I mean, once I split 1 column, I stack it and then repeat the same steps for other columns.
Although I have no problem with running the code, I am looking for a way to do it more efficiently.

I am currently repeating the same process 10-12 times and it takes some time to run the code as there are 50+ column names.

```
df1 = (df1.set_index(['Announced Date', 'Completed Date', 'Target Company',
                      'Target Dominant Sector', 'Target Dominant Country', 'Target State',
                      'Target Financial Advisor', 'Target Legal Advisor', 'Target Broker', 
                      'Target Accountant', 'Target PR', 'Target Consultant',
                      'Bidder Company', 'Bidder Dominant Country', 'Bidder State',
                      'Bidder Financial Advisor', 'Bidder Legal Advisor', 'Bidder Broker', 
                      'Bidder Accountant', 'Bidder PR', 'Bidder Consultant', 
                      'Seller Company', 'Seller Dominant Country', 'Seller State', 
                      'Seller Financial Advisor', 'Seller Legal Advisor', 'Seller Broker', 
                      'Seller Accountant', 'Seller PR', 'Seller Consultant',
                      'Reported Revenue Multiple Y1', 'Reported EBIT Multiple Y1', 'Reported EBITDA Multiple Y1', 
                      'Reported PE Multiple Y1', 'Reported Book Value Multiple Y1', 'Deal Description', 
                      'Deal Type', 'Deal Nature', "Deal Value USD(m)", 
                      'Deal ID', 'Deal within regular criteria','Target companies', 
                      'Target FAs', 'Taget LAs', "Taget Brokers", 
                      "Target Accountants", 'Target PRs','Target Consultants',
                      'Bidder Companies', 'Bidder FAs', 'Bidder LAs', 
                      "Bidder Brokers", "Bidder Accountants","Bidder PRs",
                      "Bidder Consultants",'Seller Companies']).stack()
        .reset_index(level=[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,
                          29,30,31,32,33,34,35,36,37,38,39,40,41,42,43,44,45,46,47,48,49,50,51,52,53,54,55], name='Seller FAs')
        .reset_index(drop=True))
```

I know that instead of typing all column names, I can use

`df1.columns`

and instead of using 0-55 numbers individually, I can use

`np.arange(56)`

But I am not able to incorporate those in the code. Could someone please help me make it more efficient??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use:

```
df1 = (df1.set_index(df1.columns.tolist())
          .stack()
          .reset_index(level=np.arange(56))
          .reset_index(drop=True))
```

But maybe [`DataFrame.melt`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.melt.html) should be better here:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({
         'A':[4,5,4],
         'B':[7,2,3],
         'C':[1,3,1],
})

print (df1)
   A  B  C
0  4  7  1
1  5  2  3
2  4  3  1

df1 = df1.rename_axis('a').reset_index().melt('a',var_name='b', value_name='c')
print (df1)
   a  b  c
0  0  A  4
1  1  A  5
2  2  A  4
3  0  B  7
4  1  B  2
5  2  B  3
6  0  C  1
7  1  C  3
8  2  C  1
```

If necessary sorting:

```
df2 = df1.sort_values(['a','b'])
print (df2)
   a  b  c
0  0  A  4
3  0  B  7
6  0  C  1
1  1  A  5
4  1  B  2
7  1  C  3
2  2  A  4
5  2  B  3
8  2  C  1
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response @jezrael. I have tried melt but was not successful. I was able to achieve the desired result with stack instead. I will try this and will let you know in 5 minutes. Thank you once again.

Comment: @AmandeepSaluja = One thing - all columns are passed to `set_index` ?

Comment: Hi @jezrael. I tried the above method. The code until ``` df1 = (df1.set_index(df1.columns.tolist())
          .stack()``` works perfectly but np.array shows error. I think it is because when I stack the split columns, I am renaming it as 'Seller FAs'' (in the above case). Any idea how can I achieve it?

Comment: @AmandeepSaluja - Is possible check `melt` solution? I think it should be better here

Comment: Okay. I will do some more research on melt and get back to you on this. Thanks for the help. I will mark the above comment as answers. Thanks again.

Comment: @AmandeepSaluja - Main difference is different order of columns after `set_index + stack` vs `melt`, so necessary `melt + sort_values`. thank you.

Comment: Okay. Thanks for the explanation @jezrael. I am still new to python (only 1 month). So, I still need to do some research and understand it more properly. Still, thanks for all the help. I really appreciate it.

Comment: @AmandeepSaluja - No problem you are new. I have one good advice for you. If working with real data try first filter first 5 rows and 3 columns like `df1 = df.iloc[:5, :3]` and test solution with small filtered data. If all working like need, try apply solution to all data. Because if working with real data obviosuly is not easy testing, if working well. :) Happy coding!

Comment: That is indeed an amazing advice @jezrael. I will definitely start doing it. In fact, will start doing it right now. Thanks and have a great day. :)